# Populating an array when creating a record in MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am writing an application that keeps track of members and their certifications. Each member has some arrays that refer to other models as described in the [Mongoose population docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

#### `Member` schema

```
{
  name: {
    first: String,
    last: String
  },
  unit: Number,

  // more stuff

  class_year: Number,
  campus_box: String,
  campus_address: String,

  // more stuff

  emails: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Email' }],
  certifications: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Certification' }],
  service_credits: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ServiceCredit' }]
}
```

#### `Certification` schema

```
{
  type: String,
  issue: Date,
  expiry: Date,
  number: String,
  _member: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Member' }
}
```

The schemata for `Email` and `ServiceCredit` are similar in that they both have the `_member` field.

When I create an `Email`, it is added to the `Email` model and I can subsequently perform

```
var Email = mongoose.model('Email');
Email.findOne().populate('_member').exec(function (err, email) {
  console.log(email._member.name.first);
});
```

However, it is not added to the array in the `Member` schema, because when I run

```
var Member = mongoose.model('Member');
Member.findOne().populate('emails').exec(function (err, member) {
  res.json(200, member);
});
```

I get `emails: []` in the JSON, when there is clearly an `Email` associated with that member.

I have read on the Mongoose API that the document itself needs to be populated, so I'm trying to do what is referenced at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate with the following:

```
var Member = mongoose.model('Member');
Member.findOne({ _id: req.session.member._id }, function (err, member) {
  member.populate('emails', function (err) {
    console.log('populated emails');
  });
});
```

But I get the error: `(member's JSON data) has no method 'populate'`. I know I'm trying to run `populate` on the wrong thing, but I can't figure out what the correct way would be.

Comment: You have to add the `ObjectId` of the new `Email` to the `emails` array of the appropriate `Member` manually; are you doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also encountered issues with populating array, the schema you defined will create a sub-doc for each array element (try dumping the array).

Try changing the schema to:

`emails: [ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ]`

and use

```
Member.findOne().populate({ path: 'emails', model: 'Email' }).exec(function (err, member) {
    res.json(200, member);
});
```

to populate the array.